# Can one go from being an Aveil to being an Onein?

Tags: halacha-theory, mourning-aveilus, onen

A person is an onein while taking care of arrangements for a burial, and, from what I have learned, if that person's work is finished and that person leaves the body or the body leaves the person for the last time, the status of Aveilut begins (even when the body has not been buried).

However, what if that Aveilut began and then the person was needed for a problem that arose unexpectedly. Does the person, now saddled with a new and unexpected preoccupying concern, resume status as an onein and what impact would this have on the computation of the days of shiva?

Comment: Your claim that once burial arrangements are complete a mourner shifts from onein to Aveilut is HiGHLY debated

Comment: I was told by two different poskim that that was the practice to follow (not that the arrangements are complete but that the person ceases to be involved with the dead person) -- once the "final interaction" ended, the person is no longer an onein.

Comment: @JoshK it's not highly debated in principle, just how it applies in modern times is.

Comment: See YD 375:3 and :7. Seemingly one does not stop shiva unless it began by mistake.

Comment: It may not be possible but based on the Chachmas Adam 153, there can be a case where one can go from an non-Onen to an Onen to a non-Onen. If one is abroad and there is family in local proximity to the deceased who will deal with the burial, the one abroad is a non-Onen, and then let's say the local family member becomes incapacitated, the remote family member will then have to take care of the burial and thus become an Onen and if the local family member becomes able again, the remote family member should lose the status of  Onen as they are no longer dealing with the burial.